# Ignite LINQ provider projection support for non-anonymous types

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm trying to use projection in my LINQ query, found following example on https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/net-specific/net-linq:

```
var query = ignite.GetCache<EmployeeKey, Employee>(CacheName).AsCacheQueryable().Where(emp => emp.Value.IsIntern);
...
var custom = query.Select(emp => new {Id = emp.Key, Name = emp.Value.Name, Age = emp.Value.Age});
```

It seems that only C# anonymous types are supported right now. I tried to use queries below but they failed with NotSupportedException:

```
var query = ignite.GetCache<EmployeeKey, Employee>(CacheName).AsCacheQueryable().Where(emp => emp.Value.IsIntern);
...
var custom1 = query.Select(emp => new Employee { Id = emp.Key, Name = emp.Value.Name, Age = emp.Value.Age});
var custom2 = query.Select(emp => new Employee(emp.Key, emp.Value.Name, emp.Value.Age));
```

Are there any plans to support classes in select methods? When to expect this feature?

PS: Select projection with constructor call actually works but you cannot use Where clause after Select method. I've updated ThinClientSqlExample.LinqExample method from Apache.Ignite.Examples:

```
            IQueryable<Employee> query = cache.AsCacheQueryable()
                .Select(emp => emp.Value)               
                .Select(emp => new Employee(emp.Name, emp.Salary, emp.Address, null, null))
                .Where(emp => emp.Salary > 0);
```

And received exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Expression not supported: new Employee([emp].Value.Name, [emp].Value.Salary, [emp].Value.Address, null).Salary'
```

Had a lot of debugging of Apache.Ignite/Remote.Linq and found a workaround to support Where method call after Select with constructor:

```
        public class SetNewExpressionMembersVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            protected override Expression VisitNew(NewExpression node)
            {
                var constructorParameters = node.Constructor.GetParameters();
                var typeMembers = node.Type.GetMembers();
                var constructorMembers = new MemberInfo[constructorParameters.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < constructorParameters.Length; i++)
                {
                    var parameter = constructorParameters[i];
                    var member = typeMembers.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.Name, parameter.Name, true) == 0);
                    if (member == null)
                    {
                        throw new NullReferenceException($"Unable to find member of type '{node.Type.FullName}' for '{parameter.Name}' constructor parameter");
                    }

                    constructorMembers[i] = member;
                }


                return Expression.New(node.Constructor, node.Arguments, constructorMembers);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> query.Select(emp => new Employee(emp.Key, emp.Value.Name, emp.Value.Age));

Constructor call projections should work, can you double check this? It works for me on recent Ignite versions (2.8+).

> query.Select(emp => new Employee(emp.Key, emp.Value.Name...

MemberInit projections are not supported, I've filed a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14343), you can expect it in the next release.

As a workaround, use intermediate anonymous type projection:

```
var custom1 = query.Select(emp => new { Id = emp.Key, Name = emp.Value.Name})
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(emp => new Employee { Id = emp.Id, Name = emp.Name});
```

Comment: I've downloaded Apache.Ignite solution from github.com/apache/ignite and updated query in ThinClientSqlExample.LinqExample method:

            IQueryable<Employee> query = cache.AsCacheQueryable()
                .Select(emp => emp.Value)               
                .Select(emp => new Employee(emp.Name, emp.Salary, emp.Address, null))
                .Where(emp => emp.Salary > 0);
Exception:
System.NotSupportedException: 'Expression not supported: new Employee([emp].Value.Name, [emp].Value.Salary, [emp].Value.Address, null).Salary'

Comment: @OlegBevz Oh, I see, there is filtering after the projection. I'll see if we can support this too, even though it looks a bit weird to me.

Comment: I've already found a workaround, described it in main question. In short: you should populate NewExpression.Members to force Remote.Linq generate correct query.